# Strong Markov Property of the joint process $(B_t,L_t)_{t\ge 0}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-chains

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $L=(L_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be its local time in zero. Given two strictly increasing functions $\phi_1$, $\phi_2: \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ such that $\phi_1(0)=\phi_2(0)=0$, let us define two stopping times by
$$\tau_1=\inf\Big\{t>0: B_t\notin \big(-\phi_1(B_t),\phi_1(B_t)\big)\Big\}$$
and $\tau_2=\tau_1$ if $B_{\tau_1}\notin\big(-\phi_2(B_{\tau_1}),\phi_2(B_{\tau_1})\big)$ and
$$\tau_2=\inf\Big\{t>\tau_1: B_t\notin \big(-\phi_2(B_t),\phi_2(B_t)\big)\Big\}, \mbox{ else}.$$
Could we show 
$$\mathbb E\big[\lambda(B_{\tau_2})\big|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}\big]=\mathbb E\big[\lambda(B_{\tau_2})\big|B_{\tau_1}, L_{\tau_1}\big]?$$ 
Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: @ CodeGolf : Hi first what is $\lambda$ standing for in your last equation ? Second why do you think the Local time is involved ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $\lambda$ stands for a bounded continuous function.

Comment: It is true that $B_{\tau_2}-B_{\tau_1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}$, but the law of $B_{\tau_2}-B_{\tau_1}$ depends on $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}$

Comment: @ CodeGolf : so what ?

Comment: So I would like to know whether the law of $B_{\tau_2}-B_{\tau_1}$ depends uniquely on $(B_{\tau_1},L_{\tau_1})$ by the construction of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$

Comment: @ CodeGolf : Sorry I still don"t get why and how $\tau_1$ has anything to do with local time maybe you could elaborate on this point. I think that any $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}$-measurable function can be written as a measurable function of $B_{\tau_1}$ so why do you introduce local time ? Best regards